# how to paginate in drive.permissions.list using google-api-python-client

Tags: google-drive-api, gcloud, google-api-python-client

##### My Problem

I have a GDrive folder of which I want to list the users having access to it. Unfortunately the API doesn't return more than 100 users and the documented solutions to paginate don't work.

(!) Maybe this is related to testing on shared drives - currently I cannot reproduce on non-shared drive folders unfortunately.

##### What I Tried so far:

I tried the pagination solution as described [in the google docs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/pagination.md), e.g. I tried:

```
file_id = "12abcde"  # my folder ID
request = service.permissions().list(
  fileId=file_id, fields="permissions(type,emailAddress)", supportsAllDrives=True
)
while request is not None:
    activities_doc = request.execute()
    request = service.permissions().list_next(request, activities_doc)
```

the request in the loop is always None.

The returned body from the initial request as well doesn't match the one described [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/list#response-body).

Does somebody have experience on making this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the full list, you need to use the `nextPageToken` and place it under the `pageToken` parameter.

You can get the [nextPageToken](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/list#:%7E:text=Fields-,nextPageToken,-string) from the response body by adding it to the requested fields.

You can use the following sample code as reference:

```
    try:

        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
        file_id = "asdfasdfas"  # my folder ID
        permissions_list = []
        first_request = service.permissions().list(
                fileId=file_id, 
                pageSize=100, 
                supportsAllDrives=True, 
                fields="nextPageToken, permissions(type,emailAddress)"
            ).execute()
        
        permissions_list.append(first_request)

        next_Page_Token = first_request.get('nextPageToken')

        

        while next_Page_Token:

            request = service.permissions().list(
                pageToken = next_Page_Token,
                fileId=file_id,
                pageSize=100, 
                supportsAllDrives=True, 
                fields="nextPageToken, permissions(type,emailAddress)"
            ).execute()
            permissions_list.append(request)
            next_Page_Token = request.get('nextPageToken')

            

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

### Update:

This one is a sample using `list_next()` base in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/python/latest/drive_v2.permissions.html#list:%7E:text=to%20this%20list.%0A%20%20%7D-,list_next(previous_request%3D*%2C%20previous_response%3D*),-Retrieves%20the%20next):

```
    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        permission_list = []
        token = 'test'

        fileID='folderID'

        request_made =  service.permissions().list(
            fileId=fileID,
            pageSize=100, 
            fields="nextPageToken, permissions(type,emailAddress)",
            supportsAllDrives=True
            )

        request = request_made.execute()
        permission_list.append(request)

        while token:
            nextpage = service.permissions().list_next(
                previous_request=request_made, 
                previous_response=request)
            request = nextpage.execute()
            token = request.get('nextPageToken')
            permission_list.append(request)
            request_made = nextpage


    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

Comment: Ah okay, one has to explicitly add use the nextPageToken (and retrieve via fields) when using this. Thanks a lot, this helped me a lot!

Comment: Cool, glad to here it. And thanks to you, I learnerd about the `list_next()` method.

Comment: Great, happy to hear that :)

Comment: This put me on the right track, but the code still looks overcomplicated, TBH. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77911196/1450294) instead?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the Drive API, but in a fairly modern Python implementation (e.g. 3.11), I'm pretty sure
[Giselle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17390145/giselle-valladares)'s [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76775097/1450294) could be simplified like this:

```
try:
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    permissions_api = service.permissions() # permissions in Giselle's code
    permissions = [] # permission_list in Giselle's code

    request = permissions_api.list(
        fileId='folderID',
        fields='nextPageToken, permissions(type,emailAddress)',
        supportsAllDrives=True)
    while request:
        response = request.execute()
        permissions += response
        # permissions += response.get('permissions', []) maybe this, actually?
        request = permissions_api.list_next(request, response)

except HttpError:
    logging.warning('whoopsie!', exc_info=True)  # TODO

pprint.pp(permissions) # Here they all are
```

You might actually want to append a submapping of `response` to `permission_list`, like in the line I commented out (I'm not sure about the structure), but there shouldn't be any need to mess with pagination tokens in your code. The default `pageSize` should be fine, too.